# File upload in AJAX modal window (lift)

Tags: ajax, scala, lift

Has anyone managed to create working file upload within AJAX modal window in lift? I tried using something like this:

```
ajaxForm(
    bind("upload", template,
        "file" -> SHtml.fileUpload(processFile _),
        "submit" -> SHtml.ajaxSubmit("Submit", () => { 
            println("Submitted") 
            Noop
        })
    )
)
```

And when I press "Submit" button function connected to button is executed (i see "Submitted" on console), but `processFile` is omitted and I cannot do anything with uploaded file.

I'm using List 2.3 and Scala 1.8.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are crossing your wires here.  The SHtml.fileUpload is intended to be used within a Form to capture the FileParamHolder on submission.  As you know this will cause a POST to your action URL which may not help with your modal.  If you see the example at the Exploring Lift page for [fileUpload](http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-6.html#entry-File-uploads-0), you will see the fileUpload usage:

```
bind("e", in,
     ...
     "receipt" -> SHtml.fileUpload(fileHolder = _),
     "tags" -> SHtml.text(tags, doTagsAndSubmit))
}
```

You're using an ajaxSubmit which doesn't send a form, it just calls a method on the server side and returns the JsCmd - in  your case the println _Noop. That is why you aren't seeing any file.

If you want to do an ajax style fileUpload check out [this link](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/AJAX_File_Upload) to see an example. There is also a working example on github [here](https://github.com/lunserv/lift_ajax_fileupload) that makes use of the awesome [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) plugin.